# Pandas groupby a column with numbers and lists of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

After resampling some data I have a Dataframe with two columns.  One is 'datetime' the other is a mix of float64 values and lists of float64 values as shown below.  The index is timestamp.  I want to group the values column by timestamp and then aggregate the groups.  For example, find the mean for all the numbers with a timestamp of 23:45 i.e. including the numbers in the lists.

I have tried using 'mean' but get the error: "No numeric types to aggregate".  If I do the following I get a stream of data not broken up by groups:

```
def mash(g):
        print(g)

source = data15[["values"]].groupby("Time").apply(lambda x: mash(x))
```

Example data:

```
23:45:00 2017-09-24 23:45:00                                           0
23:45:00 2017-01-23 23:45:00                                 2.09229e+08
23:45:00 2017-09-25 23:45:00  [216016810.62, 216100659.19, 216436900.77]
23:45:00 2017-09-26 23:45:00                                 1.23813e+08
23:45:00 2018-11-29 23:45:00                                 2.23831e+07
23:45:00 2017-09-27 23:45:00                                -5.40252e+07
23:45:00 2017-09-28 23:45:00                                  4.5238e+07
23:45:00 2017-09-29 23:45:00              [-119122686.64, -172455686.64]
```

Note that for this data the correct mean would be the sum of all the values divided by their number (there are 11 in total).  One way would be to flatten each list so that one list becomes several new rows each with the same index and I can use 'groupby("Time").mean()':

```
23:45:00 2017-09-29 23:45:00              [-119122686.64, -172455686.64]

becomes

23:45:00 2017-09-29 23:45:00              -119122686.64
23:45:00 2017-09-29 23:45:00              -172455686.64
```

Is there a way to do this?

[SOLVED]:  The following returns a list for each index that has the statistical features I want.

```
    def mash(g):
        flat = []
        for i in g.values:
            if type(i[0]) == list:
                [flat.append(j) for j in i[0]]
            else:
                flat.append(i[0])
        mean = np.mean(flat)
        std = np.std(flat)
        per10 = np.percentile(flat, 10)
        per90 = np.percentile(flat, 90)
        return([mean, std, per10, per90])

    source = data15[["values"]].groupby("Time").apply(lambda x: mash(x))
```

That yields 'source' as rows where each row contains a list with the mean, std, etc. eg. 06:45:00     [37132.93422085889, 631998.2385994168, 0.0, 0.0]. What was interesting is that what gets passed in to '.apply()' are a series of arrays of arrays grouped by the index i.e. an array for the group containing the individual values as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First normalize your value column to the same datatype, then aggregation will be easier.

```
import numpy as np

data15['new_values'] = data15['values'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(list(x)))
source = data15[['new_values']].groupby('Time').apply(np.sum)
```

The problem with the example you have given is that `mash` doesn't return anything, so its return value is None. And that cannot be aggregated over since it is not a numerical value. If you return a numerical value from `mash`, you won't get the error you are observing.

Comment: Tnx Karthik.  The 'mash' function was just for me to see what was being passed to the 'apply'.  I expected to see both the value and the index.  I had thought of taking the mean of the list but cannot in this case.  To find the true mean of the time bin (eg. 23:45) I have to take the mean of all the values ie. the individual values and each of the values in the list.